# Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

i am getting the above error in ie 10 please give me a suggestion.it is working fine in

```
function getSelectedIndex(element, value) {
    var selectedIndex = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < element.options.length; i++) {
        if(element.options[i].value == value) {
            selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return selectedIndex;
}
```

element.options.length is giving Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference.please suggest me a sample code.
Edit : It was working for me when I was using IE11 with compatibility mode, but when I removed it and ran it in normal mode, the above issue occurred.

Comment: Assuming `element` is a `<select>` why don't you use `element.selectedIndex`?

Comment: How to you call this function?

Comment: His problem is in loading the actual element.

Comment: when i am loading an element it is giving this error

Comment: Your problem is in one of three places: 1) the call to getSelectedIndex; 2) the HTML of the desired element; 3) the way the script is inserted in the HTML

Comment: myform.freq.selectedIndex = getSelectedIndex(myform.freq, freqVal);they are calling like this

Answer (score 2):

Use `elements.options.indexOf(value)` (assuming `element` is defined, which it doesn't seem to be). By the way, your current design will return zero if the first element matches **or** there is no match at all. If you really want to write your own version of `indexOf`, better to return `-1` in the case of no match as it does.

Answer (score 0):

actually the message gives you exactly what you need to know.
you are trying to read a property of something that does not have a value, and here it is "element" or "element.options", check the place where they are set before the function call.
for IE10 it's a strict one, it doesn't support the use of
`element.options.length`

instead you should use:

`document.getElementById("optionsID").value`

I hope this helps

Comment: element.options[i].value  for this what i have to mention