# Windows Store Cordova App + WinJS: app crashes with a JavaScript runtime error on launch

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm attempting to learn how to use WinJS in a Cordova app in Visual Studio 2015. I'm currently trying to get a basic listview working as described on the [Try WinJS website](http://try.buildwinjs.com/#listview). The app launches successfully on my android phone, however on my Windows 8.1 PC the app refuses to launch past the splash screen, giving me the error `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'firstElementChild' of undefined or null reference`

My current index.html is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>WinJSTest</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/winstore-jscompat.js" ></script>

    <!-- WinJSTest CSS references -->
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Simple template for the ListView instantiation  -->
    <div class="smallListIconTextTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none">
        <div class="smallListIconTextItem">
            <div class="smallListIconTextItem-Detail">
                <h4 data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h4>
                <h6 data-win-bind="textContent: text"></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- The declarative markup necesary for ListView instantiation -->
    <!-- Call WinJS.UI.processAll() in your initialization code -->
    <div id="listView"
         class="win-selectionstylefilled"
         data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
         data-win-options="{
            itemDataSource: Sample.ListView.data.dataSource,
            itemTemplate: select('.smallListIconTextTemplate'),
            selectionMode: 'single',
            tapBehavior: 'none',
            swipeBehavior: 'none',
            layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout }
    }">
    </div>

    <script src="js/WinJS.js"></script>

    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The index.js can also be found below:

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397704
// To debug code on page load in Ripple or on Android devices/emulators: launch your app, set breakpoints, 
// and then run "window.location.reload()" in the JavaScript Console.
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
        var items = [];

        // Generate 2000 items
        for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
            items.push({ title: "Lorem Ipsum " + i, text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s " });
        }

        var itemList = new WinJS.Binding.List(items);

        WinJS.Namespace.define("Sample.ListView", {
            data: itemList
        });

        WinJS.UI.processAll();

    };

    function onPause() {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    };

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    };

} )();
```

Hopefully someone with more experience can figure out what I'm doing wrong :D

Comment: having the EXACT same issue. if I find out anything i will let you know

Comment: You forgot to tell us which line of code in which file is throwing the exception...

Comment: @BrandonPaddock I'm not at my PC at the moment, but I don't think the error included a line number.

Comment: @rymate1234 Err, I mean where was the exception thrown. I'm assuming you're running under the debugger with it set to break in when JS exceptions are thrown (i.e. via the Debug -> Exceptions dialog). This should make it fairly obvious where the problem resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check to see what the FirElement is, and whether or not it is null.

From there, you can try to find what the first child is. I use console.log like a crazy person when starting off.

So in this case, I'd start the app with:

**console.log(object)**

then

**console.log(object.firstElementChild)**

This thread explains it in a bit more detail as well: [Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002022/unable-to-get-property-options-of-undefined-or-null-reference)

Answer (score 1):

put this in your startup code somewhere. a bit funky, but works...

1. Code will append to the element.innerHTML property setter to always remove head/body afterwards.
2. Code will append to the WinJS.UI.processAll to always clean all head/body's afterwards.
3. Most of this code is stolen from an earlier poster (HeTh)
4. This should only be used for windows store apps.

   ```
   (function () {
   var winjs_drop_head_body = function (elem) {
   if (!elem.winControl)
       return;

       //var before = elem.innerHTML;
       var head = elem.firstElementChild;
       if (head.localName == 'head') {
           var body = head.nextElementSibling;
           while (body.firstElementChild) {
               elem.insertBefore(body.firstElementChild, head);
           }
           $(head).remove();
           $(body).remove();
       }
       //var after = elem.innerHTML;
   };

   var winjs_drop_head_body_all = function () {
       var heads = document.querySelectorAll('head');
       for (var h = 0; h < heads.length; h++) {
           var head = heads[h];
           if (head.parentNode.localName != 'html') {
               winjs_drop_head_body(<any>head.parentNode);
           }
       }
   };

   // drop the head after setting innerHTML
   WinJS.Utilities.ready(() => {
       var property = "innerHTML";
       var propertyDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, property);
       var getter = propertyDescriptor.get;
       var setter = propertyDescriptor.set;
       Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, property, {
           get: getter,
           set: function (value) {
               var that = this;
               setter.call(that,value);
               winjs_drop_head_body(that);
           },
           enumerable: propertyDescriptor.enumerable,
           configurable: propertyDescriptor.configurable,
       });
   });

   var oldApplyAll = WinJS.UI.processAll;
   WinJS.UI.processAll = function (rootElement?, skipRoot?) {
       var oldVal = oldApplyAll(rootElement, skipRoot);
       oldVal.done(() => {
           winjs_drop_head_body_all();
       });
       return oldVal;
   }
   ```

   })();

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found that setting innerHTML did not work as expected. The contents was always set as 
`<head></head><body>CONTENTS</body>` if contents contains markup.

Even if you set it manually in QuickWatch in the Debugger.

I think it is related to security constraints in store apps.

I have written a function to delete the head and body elements:

```
export function winjs_drop_head_body_all() {
        var heads = document.querySelectorAll('head');
        for (var h = 0; h < heads.length; h++) {
            var head = heads[h];
            if (head.parentNode.localName != 'html') {
                HMSMapUtil.winjs_drop_head_body(head.parentNode);
            }
        }
    }
    export function winjs_drop_head_body(elem) {
        var head = elem.firstElementChild
        if (head.localName == 'head') {
            var body = head.nextElementSibling;
            while (body.firstElementChild) {                
                elem.insertBefore(body.firstElementChild, head);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have called `winjs_drop_head_body_all()` at the end of `WinJS.UI.processAll().done(...)` and `winjs_drop_head_body(elem)` after each line with `.innerHTML =` in winjs.js.

This is rather a hotfix, not a real solution, but I have found no other way yet.

Hope someone can find a better solution.

Comment: I have cut it down a little more. In winstore-jscompat.js there is a property setter defined for innerHTML. In the function cleanse(html) there is a call to createHTMLDocument, which generates the head and body elements.